# nested Angular views with IE8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

TLDR:

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NeUWHh?p=preview

error at IE8 console: TypeError: 'childNodes' is null or not an objectundefined

seems very simple, works on any webkit browser and also on IE above 9,
but breaks on IE8 and displaying the uc-compiled form of the inner view(with curly braces and field names).

My exact code, which is different from the sample code:

jobgrid.html:

```
<div class="jobContainer">  
    <div class="largeBlock">
        <div>
            <div class="access clicks">
                <a href="#/jobs/{{job.id}}"><h5 class="hasLabel" data-ng-bind="job.title"></h5></a>
                <span class="miniLabel" restrict access="admin recruiter"><a href="#/editJob/{{job.id}}">Edit</a></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section" data-ng-bind="job.department.name">

        </div>
        <div class="section" data-ng-bind="job.locations[0].name">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="smallBlock">

        <div class="access" restrict access="recruiter admin">
            <div class="section enlarged">
                <a href="#/applicants?job={{job.id}}" data-ng-bind="job.job_stats.applicants_count.total"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                Applicants
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="access" restrict access="scouter">
            <div class="section enlarged">
                <a href="#/applicants?job={{job.id}}" data-ng-bind="job.job_stats.applicants_count.referred"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                Applicants
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="smallBlock">
        <div class="access" restrict access="scouter recruiter admin">
            <div class="section enlarged">
                <a href="#/views/{{job.id}}">0</a>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                Views
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="smallBlock buttons">
        <!-- only if the company allows public distribution -->
        <div class="access" restrict access="scouter recruiter admin">
            <div class="section">
                <input type="button" class="tiny button" data-ng-click="layout.toggleShareSection(job.id)" value="Share">
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <input type="button" class="tiny button" data-ng-click="layout.toggleReferSection(job.id)" value="Refer">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="largeBlock">
        <!-- only if the company allows public distribution -->
        <div class="section enlarged top" data-ng-bind="job.reward">

        </div>
        <div class="section enlarged date">
            <i class="foundation-star" data-ng-bind="job.modified | date:'d, MMM'"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

dash.html:

```
<div class="metaContainer" data-ng-controller="dashCtrl" data-ng-cloak>
    <h1>{{model.title}}</h1>
    <div class="topbox">
        <div class="topboxSection">
        </div>
        <div class="topboxSection">
            <div class="topboxSubSectionLarge">
                <a class="small button">Share all jobs</a>
            </div>
            <div class="topboxSubSectionLarge">
                <a class="small button">Copy my job link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="topbox">
        <div class="topboxSection">
            <div class="topboxSubSectionLarge">
                <select data-ng-model="model.formData.location_id" data-ng-options="id as name for (id, name) in model.locationsList()">
                     <option value=''>Location</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="topboxSubSectionLarge">
                <div class="wideFieldContainer">
                    <select data-ng-options="id as name for (id, name) in model.departmentsList()" 
                    data-ng-model="model.formData.department_id">
                        <option value=''>Department</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="topboxSection">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="innerContainer">
                <hr>
                <div data-ng-repeat="job in model.myJobs()" data-ng-cloak>
                    <div data-ng-include src="'partials/jobgrid.html'"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please follow this tutorial. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie.

Comment: Already did, I am using the ng-include directive as an attribute with data- prefix.
And also have all the needed polyfils done in my index.html

Comment: Because I am not seeing that in the plunker that's why I asked.

Comment: If you are using the ng directives as attributes, with data- prefix and targeting IE8, you should theatrically have no problem, which is part of the reason why this is so frustrating

Comment: Make sure you have `document.createElement('ng-view');` defined. You need to pre create all directives elements like this. Try it please.

Comment: Thanks, but I alread have this line of code inside of an LT IE 10 condition - to make sure

Answer (score 1):

Can you update your script file also..

Use this

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
    <head>
      <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <script src="/path/to/json2.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
      ...
    </body>
  </html>
```

[IE 8 Fix](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

if you use $http.delete api call replace it $http["delete"]